# Split string between two delimiters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a string in a HTML source code with starting `<!--sliderStart-->` and ending `<!--sliderEnd-->`

Example1:

```
<!--sliderStart-->
<p>blah</p>
<p>blah2</p>
<!--sliderEnd-->
```

Example2:

```
<!--sliderStart--><p>blah</p><p>blah2</p><!--sliderEnd-->
```

This is my pattern, but it's not working efficiently:

```
$pattern = "/<!--sliderStart-->[^\n]+(.*?)<!--sliderEnd-->/";
```

What's the exact pattern for this matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expression dots don't match newlines unless you tell them to. You need a `s` modifier at the end of your regex, like so:

```
$pattern = '/<!--sliderStart-->(.*?)<!--sliderEnd-->/s';
```

Comment: +1 I totally forgot about the `s` modifier. Should catch up on some sleep.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using `[^\n]+` in your regex? That tells the regex engine *not* to match newlines, which you *do* want to match.

Simply get rid of it, and you're good to go:

```
$pattern = "/<!--sliderStart-->(.*?)<!--sliderEnd-->/s";
```

**Update**: Don't forget the `s` modifier at the end, so that the `.` also matches newlines.
Thanks @Palladium.